# Best approach to send big files to a server in a automatic way using a rest api?

Tags: rest, sendfile, server

I need to to send files to a server using rest api. I cannot use a browser as a client and the file should be sent with a http method. It has to be made automatically (using jenkins or so).

All I want to know is what is the best approach. The best way to do this. I have found several info but always using a form in the client side. I cannot use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also without form. What about encoding it in base64?

Look to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083908/2413391), by far the best I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to simply `PUT` the file to the target URI. If you need to upload larger files, you might want to split it in parts and join them later, when finished.