# How to upload image along with other data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie in AngularJS and learning login/registring functionality in AngularJS from http://www.angularcode.com/user-authentication-using-angularjs-php-mysql/
tutorial. In this tutorial there is no image upload functionality in signup, and I want to upload image along with other information. How will I do it !?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly be clear in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two choices :

1. Send the image file together with additional data.For this to work the request content type should be multipart/form-data.
   Look at :
   http://shazwazza.com/post/Uploading-files-and-JSON-data-in-the-same-request-with-Angular-JS
2. Upload the image to the server ,receive its id and then send the id to the server together with the additional data.
   Look at : 
   [Posting a File and Associated Data to a RESTful WebService preferably as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-data-to-restful-webservice-as-json)

Comment: thanks for the links!! But fix the first one (shazwazza) because both are pointing to the same stackoverflow link.