# Upload photo without form (API)

Tags: symfony

I'm making an app mobile and I need to upload a photo from my camera via my API. But when doctrine try to `INSERT INTO`, he isn't happy because my `name` field is `null`. So the name generate by my entity is missing.

I don't understand where the code block. My web app uses already the same entity photo and everything works fine.

My Api controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * @throws AccessDeniedException
 * @return array
 * @FOSRest\View()
 */
public function apiUploadAction()
{
    $photo = new Photo;
    $photo->setUser($this->getUser());
    $photo->setFile = new UploadedFile(
        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
        $_FILES["file"]["name"],
        $_FILES["file"]["type"],
        $_FILES["file"]["size"],
        $_FILES["file"]["error"],
        $test = false
    );

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($photo);
    $em->flush();

    $apiResponse = array(
        "code"      => true,
        "style"     => "success",
        /*********** SCREENSHOT COMES FROM HERE ***********/
        "message"   => $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."    ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."    ".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."    ".$_FILES["file"]["size"]."    ".$_FILES["file"]["error"],
    );

    $view = View::create();
    $view->setFormat('json');
    $view->setData($apiResponse);
    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

The $apiResponse.message (screenshot):

[image]

As you can see symfony has the image so the problem don't come from my app mobile. new UploadedFile(); is the right way ? To upload without form.

Comment: You can try to look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-data-to-restful-webservice-as-json). It provides a briefly good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

Replace :

```
$photo->setFile = new UploadedFile(
        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
        $_FILES["file"]["name"],
        $_FILES["file"]["type"],
        $_FILES["file"]["size"],
        $_FILES["file"]["error"],
        $test = false
    );
```

by

```
$photo->setFile($this->getRequest()->files->get('file'));
```