# How can I pass a picture to a Rails API app as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a Rails API that I want to take a file as a parameter.  I've done this before in a traditional Rails app using the file input, but Im not exactly how I can do that using cURL, Advance REST Client, etc.

Comment: Here is a good answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-data-to-restful-webservice-as-json

Comment: Thanks I will check that out!  I figured there would have to be something here about this, but I couldnt find anything.