# Add file in request using AsyncHttp

Tags: java, multipart, asynchttpclient

I'm trying to do a post to an endpoint and set some form params and a file using `AsyncHttp`.

This is the code I have:

```
httpClient.preparePost(url)
    .addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationToken)
    .addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .addFormParam("type", type)
    .addBodyPart(new ByteArrayPart("file", file.getBytes()))
    .execute()
    .get();
```

Right now I am getting 4xx, but if I do it with postman it works and I get `201`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need to use or json (without form params and sending file or use multipart/form-data POST instead of json).

So, you can replace:

```
.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

to:

```
.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
```

Or (if you really need json) you should delete `.addFormParam("type", type)` and use something like this:

```
httpClient.preparePost(url)
    .addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationToken)
    .addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .setBody(jsonContent)
    .execute()
    .get();
```

When jsonContent is your json content. Also see this question: [Posting a File and Associated Data to a RESTful WebService preferably as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json).