# Sending Image And Metadata Using Restful - JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, http2

I am bit new to HTTP/2. I have learned that using HTTP/2 we can send multiple requests to the server without waiting for previous responses. Well I want to send an image file to the server which is large (more then 500 MB). There are following ways as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083908/3084228)

> 1. Base64 encode the file, at the expense of increasing the data size by around 33%.
> 2. Send the file first in a `multipart/form-data` POST, and return an ID to the client. The client then sends the metadata with the ID, and
>      the server re-associates the file and the metadata.
> 3. Send the metadata first, and return an ID to the client. The client then sends the file with the ID, and the server re-associates
>      the file and the metadata.

I donont want to use first solution because it will increase the file size by 33%. I want to use 3rd solution.

As I am using HTTP/2 so my questions are

1. Can I send metadata and image simultaneously without waiting for ID from the server ?
2. If yes, then how can I implement ? Like do I have to do multithreading at server end for a client or how can I associate metadata and image with each other ?
3. If no then should I go for conventional style of HTTP/1.1 ?

I am using Restful and JSON for communication. More specifically I am using C# command-line client to send image and Asp.Net as server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multipart/related type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387) to make a request with related mime-types. i.e in your case you can send an image along with a JSON body data.

You can refer [Google drive file upload api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload) which has a very similar implementation.

Comment: The image-data will be sent as `byte[]` or base64 ?

Comment: It will be similar to that of general multipart/form-data as byte[].