# File object becomes string when pushed to an array? JS

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

My goal is to upload multiple files from a Vue.js frontend to a php/Laravel backend.

This is where I collect the files:

```
<input id="cover-file" @change="onCoverSelected" type="file" multiple>
```

This is the `onCoverSelected` method:

```
  onCoverSelected(e) {
    let files = e.target.files;
    // let fileArray = Object.values(files);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      console.log(files[1]);
      this.covers.push(files[1]);
    }
  },
```

When I `console.log` the files, they appear as actual files in the DevTools console. So far so good.

However, when I push the files to an array, they become strings! I don't understand why. My backend depends on receiving an array of file objects.

This is a screenshot from DevTools where it shows that the File object becomes a string

[image: img]

This is from my backend where I hope to receive an array of File objects, however, I receive an *empty array* when I `dd` the `covers` variable:

```
$covers = (array)json_decode($request->input('covers'));
dd($covers);
```

not using the `(array)` prints the below:

```
"[object File],[object File],[object File]"
```

How can I receive an array of `File` objects in the backend? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, File is an object, representing the binary information of a file. The issue isn't pushing them into an array, the issue is when you convert it to JSON: it will attempt to convert the File object to a string. In this case, it can't represent binary as a string, so File is simply converted to => `[object File]`.

Your 2 options are:

1. Submit POST data in a multipart form.
2. Convert the File to a base64 string, or [other similar methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443158/4875631). (Can drastically effect performance, encoding and then decoding on server side)

See another related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083908/4875631).