# How to write rest to upload multiple file by using jooby

Tags: java, file-upload, jooby

Is it possible to write REST request to upload multiple file? I searched Stack Overflow but I couldn't find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json) can guide you in the right direction:

There are several options:

1. Encode all the files base64, and post them to your REST endpoint
2. Post the files in a multipart/form-data request. See [jooby file upload](https://jooby.org/doc/#request-file-upload)

I created a small [demo application](https://github.com/AZWN/JoobyMultiUploadDemo) implementing both.