# Always getting {"detail":"Unsupported media type \"application/json\" in request."} error when I try to post data on postman

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, postman

I am working on a project that requires me to upload an image. However when I am trying to upload one and posting I ma getting the above error. I have no clue what to do anymore.

I have already tried using FileUploadParser and creating class Base64ImageField too. Please Help.

models

```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=unique_rand)
     emailVerified = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, default=None)
    facebookId = models.CharField( null=True,unique=True, default=None,max_length=255)
    googleId = models.CharField(null=True,unique=True,default=None,max_length=255)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    mobile = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex, MinLengthValidator(10)], max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    mobileVerified = models.NullBooleanField(null=True,default=None)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers

```
   class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      user = UserSerializer()
      avatar = Base64ImageField(required=False)
       code = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
     serializers.FileField(use_url=False)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
    image = validated_data.pop('avatar')
                                                                                          upr=UserProfile.objects.create(user=user,image=image,**validated_data)
    return upr
```

views

```
 class UserCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
user_serializer = UserSerializer
queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser)

def pre_save(self, request):
    request.avatar = self.request.FILES.get('file')

def post(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    serializer= UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: for me  - it is always something with request headers

Comment: How to work with them?  I am new to rest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using "multipart form" instead of JSON as your POST payload type. For the value (I am using Insomnia), select the dropdown on the right and select "File" instead of "Text". Then upload a file.
That worked for me, not sure if it's the same problem. Hope that helps!

Here's a post that has the answer you're looking for.

[Posting a File and Associated Data to a RESTful WebService preferably as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json)

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine, I was working on a project and encountered this issue. This thread is old but I will answer anyways.

I believe you are passing data as JSON, in POSTMAN. You just need to add `JSONParser` in you `parser_classes`

so updated `parser_classes` will be:

```
parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser, JSONParser)
```

I hope it solves your problem.
Have a great day!