# Spring Boot, upload any amount of files in REST controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'd like to create an endpoint which accepts any amount od different files from user.

For example:

[image]

Then, I'd like to receive it in my controller as a `Map<String, FilePart>` (or any other structure from which I'll know which file is which):

```
{
    "file1": "cactus-logo.png",
    "file2": "logo.png",
    "file3": "logo.png" (this one is actually different than file2 but has the same name)
}
```

---

---

---

I tried some combinations of `@RequestPart`...

1. When I do:

   ```
   @RequestPart Map<String, FilePart> files
   ```

or

```
    @RequestPart MultiValueMap<String, FilePart> files
```

I'm getting:

> org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Required request part 'files' is not present"

2. When I do:

   ```
   @RequestPart("files") List<FilePart> files
   ```

I need to submit files like that:

[image]

And then I don't have the information which file is which (if they have the same name):

[image]

3. Finally, I can do:

   ```
        @RequestPart("file1") FilePart file1,
        @RequestPart("file2") FilePart file2,
        @RequestPart("file3") FilePart file3
   ```

And then it works as expected, but with that, it's possible to submit always only 3 files. I'd like to submit any number of files.

4. As suggested in comments:

   ```
        @PutMapping(value = "/{component}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
        public void upload(
             @RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> files
        ) throws IOException {
   ```

and the map is always empty:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See this answer and see whether it helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json#:~:text=Send%20the%20file%20first%20in,an%20ID%20to%20the%20client.

Answer (score 2):

[image: result]You should use `@RequestParam`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void upload(@RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> body) {

}
```

Then post via form-data media ie:

```
file1: select file
file2: select file
file3: select file
....
```

Comment: In that way, the map is always empty

Comment: Did you try it? I just attach an image of the IDE's debugger

Comment: This should work, also passing `MultipartRequest` as parameter to the method and using  it's `getFileMap` method works. But you would have to have your files with different keys.

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải yes, I've edited my question and added screnshots

Comment: @michalk this gave me a clue. I'm using webflux and it's slightly different, but thanks to you I have found a solution. I'll post it in few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @Mariusz.v7 such details should definitely be present in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not mention I'm using reactive webflux, thus solution posted by @Toàn Nguyễn Hải does not work in my case. I believe it works in non-reactive applications.

For web flux, the following works:

[image]

To be fair, I won't accept any answer, because both of them are fine.

Thanks!