# ASP Net Core3.1 AJAX Post Sending NULL to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

It has been 3 days am trying to sending the [POST] form data using ajax, Javascript & HTML into MVC controller but getting null.

Please find the controller and ajax code please help me on this also let me know is it possible or not to send the data from ajax to mvc controller?

I am beginner .....thanks in advance.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewBug([FromBody] BugTrackerRequest bugTrackerRequest)
{
    // BugTrackerResponse bugTrackerResponse = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var Request = await _projectDetails.CreateNewBug(bugTrackerRequest);

        if (Request > 0)
        {
            BugTrackerResponse bugTrackerResponse = new BugTrackerResponse();
            bugTrackerResponse.Issuccess = true;
            // return Ok(new {Messgage="Data save successfully in the DB"});     
            return Ok();
        }
    }
    return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "Something went wrong" });
    // return bugTrackerResponse;
    //return StatusCode();

}
```

---

```
public class BugTrackerRequest:APIResponse
    {
        public int TicketId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string AssignTo { get; set; }
        public string AssignFrom { get; set; }
        public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
        public string Impact { get; set; }
        public string Platform { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public string BugType { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
function savedetails() {
 let saveuidetails = new   BugdetailRequestclass();

 saveuidetails.ProjectName = $('#projectprojectname').val();
    saveuidetails.ProjectDescription = $('#description').val();
    saveuidetails.Title = $('#title').val();
    saveuidetails.Status = $('#status').val();
    saveuidetails.AssignTo = $('#assignto').val();
    saveuidetails.AssignFrom = $('#assignfrom').val();
    saveuidetails.Attachment = $('#Attfileupload').val;
    saveuidetails.Impact = $('#Priority').val();
    saveuidetails.Platform = $('#platform').val();
    saveuidetails.Priority = $('#Priority').val();
    saveuidetails.BugType = $('bugtype').val();
    saveuidetails.CreatedDate = $('#currentdate').val();

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/TicketController1/CreateNewBugFromBody',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(saveuidetails),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data);
        },
        error: function () { alert('Exeption:'); }
    });
 }
```

Comment: are you seeing any error in browser console?

Comment: no error  getting in the browser  console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> url: '/TicketController1/CreateNewBugFromBody',
>
> public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewBug([FromBody] BugTrackerRequest bugTrackerRequest)
> ```

First, check your request URL and the action method, it seems that you are submitting the form to the `CreateNewBugFromBody` method, instead of `CreateNewBug` action method. So try to change your code as below (I assume your controller name is `TicketController1` and you want to submit to the `CreateNewBug` method):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/TicketController1/CreateNewBug',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(saveuidetails),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data);
        },
        error: function () { alert('Exeption:'); }
    });
```

Second, please check your JQuery object `BugdetailRequestclass`, in the action method, it receives a `BugTrackerRequest` object. So, try to modify your code as below (please change the request url and the jquery selector value to yours):

```
function savedetails() {
    var saveuidetails = {};  //define a object
    saveuidetails.ProjectName = $('#ProjectName').val();
    saveuidetails.ProjectDescription = $('#Description').val();
    saveuidetails.Title = $('#Title').val();
    saveuidetails.Status = $('#Status').val();
    saveuidetails.AssignTo = $('#AssignTo').val();
    saveuidetails.AssignFrom = $('#AssignFrom').val();
    saveuidetails.Attachment = $('#Attfileupload').val;
    saveuidetails.Impact = $('#Priority').val();
    saveuidetails.Platform = $('#Platform').val();
    saveuidetails.Priority = $('#Priority').val();
    saveuidetails.BugType = $('#BugType').val();  
    saveuidetails.CreatedDate = $('#CreatedDate').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/CreateNewBug',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(saveuidetails),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data);
        },
        error: function () { alert('Exeption:'); }
    });
}
```

Besides, you could add a breakpoint in the JavaScript resource and CreateNewBug action method, and check whether you could get the correct data before/after send Ajax request.
Screenshot as below:

JavaScript debug screenshot (using F12 developer tools)

[image]

Action method debug screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Zhi Lv now it is working fine after the changes you told me to do ... also can you pls help me ,how should i improve code logic thru self pratice .

Comment: @KuwarpratapSingh: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. If you need something else, please ask a new question. BR

Answer (score 1):

Your URL in POST is wrong, please change

```
/TicketController1/CreateNewBugFromBody
```

to

```
 /TicketController1/CreateNewBug
```

Please verify that your controller class is named `TicketController1`.

To start with, please comment out

```
saveuidetails.Attachment = $('#Attfileupload').val;
```

in js and

```
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
```

When controller method is working, you may look at the `Attachment` which will be a challenge.
You basically have three choices (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083908/14072498):

1. Base64 encode the file, at the expense of increasing the data size by
   around 33%, and add processing overhead in both the server and the client
   for encoding/decoding.
2. Send the file first in a multipart/form-data POST, and return an ID to the
   client. The client then sends the metadata with the ID, and the server re-
   associates the file and the metadata.
3. Send the metadata first, and return an ID to the client. The
   client then sends the file with the ID, and the server re-associates the
   file and the metadata.

Else, your code shown here looks OK to me, and there is no problem using a MVC controller for this. If controller contains API methods only, you should extend from `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller`, and annotate controller with `[ApiController]`. The latter invokes model validation automatically.

When implementing new API end-points, always start with something simple and verify with e.g. Postman that you can reach your new end-point.