# testing upload file api with postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

I created a restful api to upload a file to an external web service, but I need to send some kind of data in this request to, here is an example of the request :

```
"file" : <MultiPartFile>,
"data" : {...}
```

I mapped this request to this class :

```
@Data
class UploadFileRequest{
   private MultiPartFile file;
   private Data data;
}
```

here is the api :

```
@PostMapping
String uploadFile(@RequestBody UploadFileRequest input){
     return service.uploadFile(input.getFile(), input.getData());
}
```

I want to know how to send this kind of request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test file upload in postman you just need to set the body to `form-data` and use type `file` to upload a file. I've tested this with [Postman Echo](https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/echo-api/) and published [an example that you can copy](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/playground/request/19391207-9fdc891c-cda7-4771-afce-4559d9598957) to your collection.

If you navigate to my example you're simply  going to find this:

[image]