# Rest API Json payload in @RequestBody vs Json file upload for data size 3 MB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

This maybe a simple question but I couldn't figure it out myself nor could I find an online resource for it.

I have to develop a REST API using spring boot. I see two options to accept the json payload (max payload size 3 MB in some cases)

**Option 1: Ask clients to send json in request body. Let Jackson convert it to Java object**

```
@RestController 
public class EmployeeController {
  
  @PostMapping
  public void createEmployees(@RequestBody List<Employee> employees) {
   // do something with employees 
  }

}
```

**Option 2: Ask clients to upload a json file and let the controller accept Multipart payload**

```
@RestController 
public class EmployeeController {

   @PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
  public void createEmployees(@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file) {
   // convert multipart file data to List of Employee objects
   //do something with employees 
  }

}
```

Which option is better and why?

Comment: check answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083908/2165146

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I am not asking for a solution for multipart file upload with metadata. The question is whether file upload is better choice than plain json payload and why?

Answer (score 0):

I think Option 1 is better. This is because if you use a file, you have to read the json payload written in the file and convert it to `List<Employee>`.

And if you use a multipartFile, you receive base64 encoded data. Since base64 encoded data expresses 8-bit data as 6-bit data, 33% increase in size occurs compared to the original.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about structured data your API uses directly, then better to upload it as `application/json`. If we are talking about some sort of attachment, which your API probably does not touch or touches it only a lot later e.g. images, PDF, etc. then better to use `multipart/form-data` and send a JSON with it, which describes the metadata of the attachment, e.g. it is a photo of a friend, etc. So I think it depends on the JSON and what you want to do with it. In your case since it will be processed, then better to send it as `application/json`. If you process it later, then still better to send it this way and make a transaction resource where you can follow the state of the processing, something like `POST /transactions {json}`.

Answer (score 0):

From this [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) the `multipart/form-data` media type came into life.

As described here

> The multipart/form-data encoding **has a high overhead and performance
>
> impact if there are many fields with short values**. However, in
> practice, for the forms in use, for example, in HTML, the average
> overhead is not significant.

So in case you just want to send a normal `json` with a large number of relative small fields like integers, booleans and small strings you should consider it affecting you badly in overhead and performance.

Comment: so, receiving a plain json in request body is a better choice in this case instead of  a json file ?

Comment: @Aman if your `json` is just multiple (large number of fields) of fields containing relative small values then I think it could lead to overhead and performance impact.