# How to read the contents of a "file" object (not local file) in express?

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api

i want to save user input including file input and post that object using fetch, like this:

```js
// ...
subBtn.addEventListener('click', requestCreate);

async function requestCreate(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  try {

    const obj = {

      method: "POST",

      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

      body: `{"title": "${name.value}", "body": "${email.value}", "file": ${file.files[0]}, "file2": ${file.files[1]}}`
    }

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/', obj);

    if (!res.ok) throw Error(res.statusText);

  } catch (error) { console.log(error) }
}
```

But i can't access the file in the backend

```js
app.post('/', (req, res)=> {

  console.log(req.body.file) // returns [object File]
  res.send({name: 'hello world'});
})

app.use(express.json())
```

I've googled whole day but found nothing that helps. i feel like iam using fetch wrong way to upload files

can somebody plz explain, if i can upload files to backend without using formData object ? is it not recommended ?

Comment: Hey, this post may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083702/11199544.
But in short, you cannot send files via JSON requests. When you stringify the `file.files[0]` object, it will turn into a string "[object File]".  If you really want to send files through JSON requests, then you'll need to base64 encode them.

Answer (score 0):

**select a single using HTML5**

```html
<label>
  img: <input accept="text/*" type="file"/>
</label>
```

**upload a single file using fetch**

```js
const input = document.querySelector(`input[type="file"]`);

function upload() {
  fetch(uplaodURL, { method: "POST", body: input.files[0] });
}

input.addEventListener("change", upload);
```

**access a single file in express**

```js
app.post('/', express.raw({ inflate: true, limit: '50mb', type: () => true }), async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log("=>", req.body.toString()) // accessing the text file
  res.json({ bodySize: req.body.length });
});
```

---

**Note:** as mentioned by "Gabriel Freitas Yamamoto" in the comment, you can access the input file by `inputElement.files`, but you can't actually send it with other input fields using json. sending `file.files[0]` object will be turned into a string "[object File]".

so you would either need to convert your file to base64 string and send it as string or send the file (including other fields) as multipart formData