# Curl command top upload file with metadata

Tags: curl, command-line

I am testing my RESTFul API, and i would like to know if there is a way to upload a file and json data at the same time.

When i run this command from command line:

`curl -v -X POST -d '{"label":"vacations", "date":"2011-01-03"}' -F photo=@"photo.png" http://localhost/album`

I get this error: 
`Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!`

Is there really a way to accomplish this?

Comment: can i also use @sputnick approach to upload audio files with metadata?

Comment: Sure wguerrero, you can upload any binary you want with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a conflict between

```
-F photo=@"photo.png"
```

and

```
-d '{"label":"vacations", "date":"2011-01-03"}'
```

you may use only one of this 2 options.

The best approach I think is to `base64 encode` the picture in a string and put it in your `JSON` like :

```
-d '{"label":"vacations", "date":"2011-01-03", "photo":"AE..."}'
```

and `base64 decode` it server side.

You can add this switch too :

```
-H 'Content-type:text/json'
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know an online service where i can encode files? i mean where the files encoded are valid.

Comment: Which OS do you use ? On linux, I can use `base64 file`

Comment: wow, i test it, but it is a very long ouptut, won't this cause any possible issue??

Comment: No, that's not an issue. POST have a high limit compared to GET method. If you have a better way, come here later to tell us how ;)

Answer (score 0):

@sputnick aproach works :).

I'll use postman (a chrome extension) to test my restful API instead of curl.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use -F for the metadata, see Erik Allik's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938569/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-metadata-using-a-rest-web-service)

something like for example:

```
curl -F 'json={"label":"vacations", "date":"2011-01-03"}' -F 'photo=@photo.png' http://localhost/album
```