# Symfony REST file upload over PUT method

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a REST service where I want to  update a file over PUT.
When I use POST I used the following to get the uploaded file:

```
/**
 * @var Request $request
 */
$request->files->get('file');
```

How to get an uploaded file send as PUT in Symfony Framework?

Comment: Do you use a specific REST bundle? Ok my bad I did not see the FOSRestBundle tag. I wrote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129874/uploading-image-file-through-api-using-symfony2-fosrestbundle/23825541#23825541) to upload an image, but it can be the same logic for a file.

Comment: I did test it but in the `$request->getContent()` is more as the content of the file there is also some header information and then the uploaded image is corrupt

Comment: I am also searching for a proper answer how to deal with this. I actually I am able to read the file with:

 `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` 

but I am not able to convert this into a proper `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` class. This is what I actually want to achieve. Any new ideas?

Comment: save the content into a tmpfile e.g. with tempnam and create a new File($path)  Symfony File is based on SplFileInfo

Answer (score 4):

When you receive a POST request, you get a form submitted with one or more fields, and these fields include any files (possibly more than one file).  The `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data`.

When you PUT a file, the file's data *is* the request body.  It's like the opposite of downloading a file with GET, where the file's content is the response body.  In this case, if you receive a JPG file via a PUT request, the `Content-Type` will be `image/jpeg`.  Of course this means you can only submit one file with each PUT request.

You should therefore use `$request->getContent()` to receive the data.  If the content has other information in addition to the submitted file, then technically speaking it is a malformed PUT request, and should probably be sent as a POST instead.

Although you can't send any other fields with a PUT request, you can still use the query string to provide some additional short fields where appropriate.  For example you might upload a file via a PUT request to `/api/record/123/attachment?filename=example.pdf`.  This would allow you to receive both an uploaded file, another data field (the filename) and the ID (123) of the record to attach the upload to.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way where you don't need to change your api you submit the file and data you want to change as method `POST` and add query parameter `?_method=PUT` to the url. In your front controller `app.php`/`index.php` you need to enable this feature with:

```
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
```