# multipart/form-data and FormType validation

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am building an API using the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/) and am at the stage where I need to implement the handling of the creation of new entities that contain binary data.

Following the methods outlined on [Sending binary data along with a REST API request](http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/02/sending-binary-data-along-with-rest-api.html#.U-xx7PmSySR)
 sending the data as `multipart/form-data` feels the most practical for our implementation due to the ~33% added bandwidth required for Base64.

**Question**

How can I configure the REST end point to both handle the file within the request and perform validation on the JSON encoded entity when sending the data as `multipart/form-data`?

When just sending the raw JSON I have been using Symfony's form `handleRequest` method to perform validation against the custom `FormType`. For example:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $comment, ['method' => 'POST']);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

  // Is valid

}
```

The reason I like this approach is so that I can have more control over the population of the entity depending whether the action is an update (PUT) or new (POST).

I understand that Symfony's `Request` object handles the request such that previously the JSON data would be the `content` variable but is now keyed under `request->parameters->[form key]` and the files within the file bag (`request->files`).

Comment: Are the requests sent to the web service made from browser or from apps/clients you can modify ?

Comment: Apps and clients we can modify

Comment: How many of your users use IE < 10? Are they negligible?

Comment: All clients will be mobile apps. Primarily native apps.

Comment: I've updated my answer to move the decode part to FOS body listener.

Comment: anything we can provide before the end of the bounty ?

Comment: @rolebi What you've provided will work for our situation since we only require `json`.

Comment: If I could just upvote this for  times :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving up and looking at an alternative option of having a separate endpoint for the image upload. For example:

1. Create the new comment.

`POST /comments`

2. Upload image to end point

`POST /comments/{id}/image`

I found there is already a bundle which provides various RESTful uploading processes. One of which was the one I originally wanted of being able to parse `multipart/form-data` into an entity whilst extracting the file.

- http://sroze.github.io/SRIORestUploadBundle/

Comment: Looks like they have implemented their own parser but does not handle binding multiple file atm @see https://github.com/sroze/SRIORestUploadBundle/issues/3

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there is no clean way to retrieve the Content-Type of the form-data without parsing the raw request.

If your API does support only json input or if you can add a custom header (see comments below), you can use this solution :

First you must implements your own `body_listener`:

```
namespace Acme\ApiBundle\FOS\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use FOS\RestBundle\Decoder\DecoderProviderInterface;

class BodyListener
{
    /**
     * @var DecoderProviderInterface
     */
    private $decoderProvider;

    /**
     * @param DecoderProviderInterface $decoderProvider Provider for fetching decoders
     */
    public function __construct(DecoderProviderInterface $decoderProvider)
    {
        $this->decoderProvider = $decoderProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'multipart/form-data') !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        $format = 'json';
        /*
         * or, using a custom header :
         *
         * if (!$request->headers->has('X-Form-Content-Type')) {
         *     return;               
         * }
         * $format = $request->getFormat($request->headers->get('X-Form-Content-Type'));
         */

        if (!$this->decoderProvider->supports($format)) {
            return;
        }

        $decoder = $this->decoderProvider->getDecoder($format);
        $iterator = $request->request->getIterator();
        $request->request->set($iterator->key(), $decoder->decode($iterator->current(), $format));
    }
}
```

Then in your config file :

```
services:
    acme.api.fos.event_listener.body:
        class: Acme\ApiBundle\FOS\EventListener\BodyListener

        arguments:
            - "@fos_rest.decoder_provider"

        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.request
                method: onKernelRequest
                priority: 10
```

Finally, you'll just have to call `handleRequest` in your controller. Ex:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('foo', 'text')
    ->add('file', 'file')
    ->getForm()
;

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Using this request format (`form` must be replace by your form name):

```
POST http://xxx.xx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="01ead4a5-7a67-4703-ad02-589886e00923"
Host: xxx.xx
Content-Length: XXX


--01ead4a5-7a67-4703-ad02-589886e00923
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=form


{"foo":"bar"}
--01ead4a5-7a67-4703-ad02-589886e00923
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=form[file]; filename=foo.txt


XXXX
--01ead4a5-7a67-4703-ad02-589886e00923--
```

Comment: when adding this code the it would produce a Notice: `Undefined property: VSmart\ApiBundle\Listener\BodyListener::$decoderProvider`. Difference with the code provided is that we dont use a form to handle the request. Though the debugger shows that $decoderProvider does exist. Any ideas?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen you can skip the `extends` part of the class and use a full service definition instead of using `fos_rest.body_listener` as `parent`. I'll update my answer

Comment: thanks that seems to work when using phpunit tests though when sending the same request via the advanced rest client the body remains empty. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: Which client do you use ?

Comment: Advanced REST Client https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: Where does the problem reside ? Do you successfully decode the JSON input ? Are the files not present ?

Comment: in the action the $request->getContents() gives an empty string. While in PHPUnit it works and I get the correct JSON.

Comment: I created a seperate question the case is probably a bit different then the original answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781823/fosrestbundle-body-empty-when-multipart-request

Answer (score 1):

Here is more clear solution: http://labs.qandidate.com/blog/2014/08/13/handling-angularjs-post-requests-in-symfony/

> Copy and pasting this code to other controllers is very WET and we like DRY!
>
> What if I told you you could apply this to every JSON request without having to worry about it? We > wrote an event listener which - when tagged as a kernel.event_listener - will:
>
> check if a request is a JSON request
> if so, decode the JSON
> populate the Request::$request object
> return a HTTP 400 Bad Request when something went wrong.
> Check out the code at https://github.com/qandidate-labs/symfony-json-request-transformer!
> Registering this event listener is really easy. Just add the following to your services.xml:
>
> ```
> <service id="kernel.event_listener.json_request_transformer" > class="Qandidate\Common\Symfony\HttpKernel\EventListener\JsonRequestTransformerListener">
>    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" priority="100" />
> </service>
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in my case since the data is being sent as `multipart/form-data` and the value of `$content` is null

Comment: @Malachi you can modify this condition to check api uri (e.g. /api/), for example, instead of Content-Type.

Comment: OP is using FOSRestBundle which provide such a [Body Listener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#body-listener)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the app to send the file content in the JSON.

1. Read the file content in you app.
2. Base64 encode the content of the file
3. Create a `JSON` with all your field (included the one with the file content)
4. Send the `JSON` to the server.
5. Handle it in the standard way.

You get the file content in a base64 encoded string. You can then decode it and validate it.

Your `JSON` will look like:

```
{
    name: 'Foo',
    phone: '123.345.678',
    profile_image: 'R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw=='
}
```

Comment: I would rather avoid using base64 due to the ~33% overhead in data required.

Comment: You can use a different encoding. This discussion might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64 (see all the comments)

Comment: Using this method, the file will not be handled directly by the form component.