# Fosrestbundle body empty when multipart request

Tags: php, rest, symfony, phpunit, fosrestbundle

In the code bellow I expect the `$request->getContents()` to get the body content of the `HTTP` request. When sending non multipart request this works as expected though when using multipart requests the `$body` variable remains empty.

```
public function postDebugAction(Request $request) {
    $body = $request->getContent();

    if (empty($body)) {
        throw new \Exception('Body empty.');
    }


    return $this->view(array(), 201);
}
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327690/multipart-form-data-and-formtype-validation/) question and answer I added a body listener aswell.

```
<?php

namespace VSmart\ApiBundle\Listener;

use FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener as BaseBodyListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use FOS\RestBundle\Decoder\DecoderProviderInterface;

class BodyListener extends BaseBodyListener {

    /**
     * @var DecoderProviderInterface
     */
    private $decoderProvider;

    /**
     * @param DecoderProviderInterface $decoderProvider Provider for fetching decoders
     */
    public function __construct(DecoderProviderInterface $decoderProvider) {
        $this->decoderProvider = $decoderProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'multipart/form-data') !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        $format = 'json';

        if (!$this->decoderProvider->supports($format)) {
            return;
        }

        $decoder = $this->decoderProvider->getDecoder($format);
        $iterator = $request->request->getIterator();
        $request->request->set($iterator->key(), $decoder->decode($iterator->current(), $format));
    }

}
```

According to my PHPUnit test this was working though when using `Postman` and `Advanced Rest Client` to simulate the request the body seems to be empty again. I double checked this to run both the simulate requests as PHPUnit with the debugger. Result is that, indeed, the body is empty when simulated via a Rest client and not empty when ran through PHPUnit.

The test case I used:

POST url:

```
http://localhost/EntisServer/web/app_dev.php/api2/debug
```

Headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer ZGYzYjY1YzY4MGY3YWM3OTFhYTI4Njk3ZmI0NmNmOWZmMjg5MDFkYzJmOWZkOWE4ZTkyYTRmMGM4NTE1MWM0Nw
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----XXXXX
```

Content:

```
-----XXXXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "blabla": 11
}

-----XXXXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="q_3101"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

contents of a file...

-----XXXXX--
```

**UPDATE**
I was uncertain whether I stepped through the debugger without using the `BodyListener`. When I did the result is exactly the same. So, without the `BodyListener` the PHPUnit case gets the body though the simulated request is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

See `php://` wrappers on php.net:

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

So update your PHP version or make sure you only read the input once.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your uploaded files in `$request->files->all()` after `fos_rest.decoder_provider` decoding.