# request.META in flask?

Tags: flask

It appears Django has request.META: a dictionary of the request's headers in CAPITAL_UNDERSCORE format - like: "X_FORWARDED_FOR".

Is there a similar construct for Flask?

(I am aware of flask's request.headers (which contains headers in "x-forwarded-for" format))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way for the framework to expose headers. Django chooses to expose it full capital with underscores and the real input from the server is something like that: `X-Forwarded-For` on apache2.

All this to say that Flask expose you headers in only one way. You can always convert it using `.upper().replace('-', '_')` if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following process, as mentioned here to create a request with a file and [metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076550/8900683) :

```
curl -F "metadata=<metadata.json" -F "file=@my-file.tar.gz" http://example.com/add-file
```

And then read the file and the metadata as follows:

```
file = request.files['file']
metadata = json.loads(request.form.get('metadata'))
```