# Multipart Form Upload Image and Json

Tags: angularjs, forms, multipartform-data

Bit stuck on this one, need to upload an image and json together using a multipart form.. not sure how to sent the content type headers or upload the image.. think i need to convert to blob.. at the moment im just sending the data i get from the file input field.

any suggestion would be great thanks

```
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': false },

        transformRequest: function (data) {

            console.log(data);

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("formatteddata", angular.toJson(data.model));


            formData.append('media', Image)

            return formData;
        },

        data: { model: shoutoutData, image: shoutoutImage}
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        alert("success!");

    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        alert("failed!");

    });
```

Comment: at first you should set type as multipart. See this topics:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Im using angularjs, this is how you set up a multipart form.. as im getting the correct output.. Just cant seem to attach image and set the content type for each part

Comment: My understanding is you can't do this. I normally upload the file/s first and then use the identifier/s returned to then send the json. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3938628/2326610)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Here is the code what i did in my project to upload image and data:- 
HTML PAGE :-
<form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitCuisine(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.name.$invalid && myForm.name.$touched }">
               <label for="name">Name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name of cuisine" ng-model="dataform.name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.description.$invalid && myForm.description.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Description</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" 
                  placeholder="Description for cuisine" ng-model="dataform.description" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.category.$invalid && myForm.category.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="dataform.category" id="category" name="category" required>
                   <option>Veg</option>
                   <option>Non-veg</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.subcategory.$invalid && myForm.subcategory.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Sub-Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="dataform.subcategory" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
                   <option>Main Course</option>
                   <option>Staters</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.price.$invalid && myForm.price.$touched }">
               <label for="description">Price</label>
               <span class="fa fa-dollar"></span>
               <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" 
                  placeholder="Price" ng-model="dataform.price" required>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="description">Image</label> 
               <input type="file"  file-input="files" name="file"/>
            </div>  
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"> Submit</button>
        </form>



Controller:-
$scope.submitCuisine=function(isvalid){
    if(isvalid){
        var fd=new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
            fd.append('file',file);
        });

        fd.append('formdata',JSON.stringify($scope.dataform));

        $http.post('admin/managecuisineAdd',fd,{
            transformRequest:angular.identity,
            headers:{'Content-type':undefined}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.status=data;
            $scope.itemlist.push(data)
            $scope.message="New Dish Added Successfully"
        });
    }   
}

Directive :-
myApp.directive("fileInput",['$parse',function($parse){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('change',function(){
                $parse(attrs.fileInput).
                assign(scope,ele[0].files)
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/yPNA0ij3Dn37tsI9w7Z2?p=preview
check the post header in firebug you will find that it is showing image in encrypted form and data in the end of it.

Comment: Thanks, tweaked you code a little but put me in the right direction.. thanks for your help...

Answer (score -1):

Use formData as conteiner like say @squiroid

In html code

```
<form ng-submit="vm.uploadFile()">
      <input type="file" id="filePhoto" name="file">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
{{vm.previewImage()}}
```

In my controller

```
vm.previewImage = previewImage;
function previewImage(){
        console.info("vm.file "+vm.file);
        var imageLoader = document.getElementById('filePhoto');
        console.info(imageLoader);
        imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImages, false);

        function handleImages(e) {
            console.info("entra handleImage");
            vm.file = e.target.files[0];
            console.info("archivo ");
            console.info(vm.file);
        }
}

vm.uploadFile = uploadFile;
function uploadFile() {
    return dataFactory.uploadFile(
        vm.file)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.info('uploadFile success');
            console.info(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.info('updauploadFileteUser fail');
            console.info(response);
        });
}
```

In DataFactory

```
function updateUser(token,file,username,email,lenguaje,colapsarMenu){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('file',file);
    //append more params if you want

    return $http
        .post('/uploadFile',
        formData,{
            transformRequest:angular.identity,
            headers: {
                //Optional token bearer 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
                'Content-type':undefined
            }
        });
}
```