# Return more that one entity in RESTful response?

Tags: rest, service, entity, entities

I'm developing a RESTful websevices project, my question is simple,
is there a way to return both 'File' and 'JSON' entities in the same response?

e.g.: suppose I have this method:

```
    @GET
        @Path("downloadFile")
        @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public Response downloadLogStream( ..... ) {
        .....
        Response.ok(resultFile);
        }
```

but I need to return another entity beside the file itself without adding additional Headers.

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can send only response but that can be a complex object. Wrap result/json and status in response.

```
return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
```

More here

```
@GET
@Path("downloadFile")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response downloadLogStream( ..... ) {
         // Assuming result is json string
         String result = " JSON is "+jsonObj;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }
}
```

File download

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = "pathTo:\\filename. Zip"; 
@GET @Path("/get")         
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) 
public Response getFile() 
  { 
   File file = new File(FILE_PATH);   
   ResponseBuilder response =    Response.ok((Object) file);   
   response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=newfile.zip");
   return response.build(); }
```

Comment: But this way you've returned only a JSON response, I want to send the File entity as well in the same response.

Comment: You should try with file download then? Will add sample code above

Comment: OK, you wrote two methods above right, one to return a JSON and another to return a File, what I want is to return BOTH the JSON and the FILE in the same Response of one method.

Comment: Do a get similar to post here - give the path to server or send the file object wrapped inside json. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938569/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-metadata-using-a-rest-web-service