# Serialize and embed uploaded files to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I have an API done with rails. I'm looking to upload multiple files in the same POST request. I would like to know if the only to do it by using form-data like [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076550/2747638)?

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "post[name]=wef" -F "post[catchphrase]=rteh reth erth erth" -F "post[posts_ids][]=8940" -F "post[screenshot1]=Ca9.png" -F "post[banner]=C34.png" -F  "post[icon]=60eb.jpg" 'http://example.com:3000/api/v1/5282/posts/111605.json?api_key=2s4ctv21vudsgreeegrge'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does that concern you? You can do manual serialization/de-serialization of your files, but why bother if browser and Rails will do that for you with `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Because for the moment all my api is a json api and I have to write blueprint documentation. For the moment I have to do thing like that. https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/100#issuecomment-48290545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base64 encoding.

**On your client side:**

HTML

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Javascript

```
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

Source: [readAsDataURL documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

If you don't use Javascript, make serializer for your platform. Data-URL is just `data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme))

**On your server side:**

Most likely you won't need to do anything at all, because paperclip/carrierwave will deserialize that stuff for you.